# Checking session array for certain value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
function CHECKITEMEXIST($cartarray, $sub){
    foreach ($cartarray as $item){
        foreach ($item as $item2){
            if($item2['subject'] = $sub){
                return '1';

            }else{
                return '0';
            }
        }
    }
}

$subject = "English";
    $checkitemexist = CHECKITEMEXIST($cart, $subject);

if($checkitemexist > 0){
    echo "Yes";
}else{
    echo "No";
}
```

Guys I have the function below to check my cart array to see whether english subject exist or not, but the problem is even when english isn't in the cart array it will still return yes result, why is that so?

Below are the sample cart array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [subject] => science ) ) )
```

Comment: You return `'0'` and `'1'`, you should change that to `0` and `1`. Stick with integers as much as you reasonably can (for performance). Also, on line4 on the 2nd piece of code you do `>0`. I suggest either `!==0` or `===1`. These are a tiny bit faster, but I personally because IMO it reads easier

Comment: Or even better, return `true`/`false` and do `if( $checkitemexist ){`

Comment: I tried. The first value I pass in English, it will return yes, but the second value I pass in Science which is also in the cart array it returns no. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

make it correct

```
if($item2['subject'] = $sub){   // = is an assignment operator
```

to

```
if($item2['subject'] == $sub){  // == is a comparison operator
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

try your modified function

```
function CHECKITEMEXIST($cartarray, $sub){
$flag = 0;
    foreach ($cartarray as $item){
        foreach ($item as $item2){
            if($item2['subject'] == $sub){
                $flag = 1;
            break;
            }
        }
        if($flag==1)
        {
            break;
        } 
    }
return $flag;   
}
```

Comment: I tried. The first value I pass in English, it will return yes, but the second value I pass in Science which is also in the cart array it returns no. I don't understand.