# php if else issue, always displays the else result

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$sublevel = $_POST['level'];
echo $sublevel;
if($sublevel == "English"){
    echo "En";
}elseif($sublevel == "Computer"){
    echo "Com";
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Why won't my if else display En or Com results? Instead it will only display "Error" even if I enter the correct value -- "English" or "Computer". I also checked the value I entered with the echo `$sublevel`.

Comment: Show your full code including your HTML form. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named tour variable `$sublevel` but check `$ordersublevel` in your if/else statements

```
$sublevel = $_POST['level'];
if($sublevel == "English"){
    echo "En";
}elseif($sublevel == "Computer"){
    echo "Com";
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

or

```
$ordersublevel = $_POST['level'];
if($ordersublevel == "English"){
    echo "En";
}elseif($ordersublevel == "Computer"){
    echo "Com";
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

**update**

Your code should work as is. The only thing I can think of that might cause the problem that you may be overlooking is leading or trailing spaces on the submitted data. Use `trim()` to remove that.

$sublevel = trim($_POST['level']);

Comment: Sorry, typo there. I have ammend the question.

Comment: That's one heckuva "typo" if you ask me. Typos consist of a letter or two, not a whole word.@user3322610

Comment: [`This question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22010652/) has something to do with it. OP needs to show full code and HTML form. I voted to close till then. **Edit**: Now shaking head as to why all of a sudden, OP decides to accept. My upvote still stands though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Because `$ordersublevel` never gets set. Only `$sublevel` does. Hence it isn't `English` or `Computer` as it's nothing.

Comment: Sorry, typo there. I have ammend the question.

Comment: @user3322610 Are you sure that you use `$_POST` for your variable and not `$_GET`? Can you post the output of `var_dump($sublevel)` to the original question with the value "Enlish"?